# STS Spring Roo not creating entity

Tags: spring-roo

I just download the full STS and created a Roo project.  I executed

```
persistence setup --provider HIBERNATE --database HYPERSONIC_PERSISTENT
```

and everything worked. Then I executed

```
database properties list
```

and I got a list of properties. Then I executed

```
entity --class ~.domain.Rsvp
```

and I got

```
Command 'entity --class ~.domain.Rsvp' not found (for assistance press CTRL+SPACE or type "hint" then hit ENTER)
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Did you try hitting CTRL+SPACE and letting the shell assist you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what version of Roo are you using? If what you are using is roo 1.2.2 or above, try the following command.

```
entity jpa --class ~.domain.Rsvp
```

Comment: Can you tell me why my original command didn't work? What is the significance of adding jpa?

Comment: Nevermind, found the command at http://static.springsource.org/spring-roo/reference/html/command-index.html#command-index-entity-jpa I wonder why they added the jpa to the command?